# Filter matched items in an array of string with another (key,value) objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, foreach

I am using angular as front end. I have below array of strings. I want to filter this "array" with matched keys of another "(key,value) objects".

String Array:

`var stringArr = ["vijay-1110","viki-1100","ram-2110","mark-2100"]`

(key,value) Objects:

```
var obj = {"viki-1100":6,"mark-2100":2}
```

To return only the non matched keys from `stringArr`,So desired output:

```
var result = ["vijay-1110","ram-2110"]
```

I haven tried the below code which doesnot return the desired output?

```
var filterFunction = function(stringArr,obj){
if(angular.equals({}, obj)){
    return stringArr;
}
else{
    _.each(stringArr,function(input,index){
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) {
            if(input === key){
                stringArr.splice[index,1];
            }
        });
    });
    return stringArr;
}
```

this wont filter the `stringArr`, It always return all the results in `stringArr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way:

```js
var stringArr = ["vijay-1110","viki-1100","ram-2110","mark-2100"]
var obj = {"viki-1100":6,"mark-2100":2}

var result = stringArr.filter(function(item){
  return !(item in obj)
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
stringArr.filter( s => typeof obj[s] != "undefined" )
```

**Edit**

I realized that OP is looking for the opposite of my answer, so simply replaced `!=` with `==`

```
stringArr.filter( s => typeof obj[s] == "undefined" )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` to check if a key exist inside an object. Use `array#filter` to iterate through your array and for each value return the non-existent value.

```js
var stringArr = ["vijay-1110","viki-1100","ram-2110","mark-2100"];
var obj = {"viki-1100":6,"mark-2100":2};
var result = stringArr.filter(name => !(name in obj));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below works and manage the case where *obj* is an empty object. *Object.keys(...).length* is here to check if obj is an empty object or not

```js
var stringArr = ["vijay-1110","viki-1100","ram-2110","mark-2100"];
var obj = {"viki-1100":6,"mark-2100":2};
var filterFunction = function(stringArr,obj){
    return stringArr.filter(str => Object.keys(obj).length === 0 || obj[str] );
}

console.log(filterFunction(stringArr, obj));
console.log(filterFunction(stringArr, {}));
```